# Change Windows 7 keyboard to AZERTY

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-layout

I just installed Windows 7 on VMware and the keyboard settings are QWERTY.

Being from Belgium, I'm used to AZERTY. Where can I find the option to change this on startup?

Comment: Lol, thanks. I doubt Superuser was made for PM'ing :p

Comment: Ok, removed comment... just know you're welcome ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control Panel > Clock, Language, and Region > Under Region and Language: Change Keyboards or other Input Methods.